# Function for making the code wait in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, java-threads, pause

Im new to using javaFx and programming in general so this might be a stupid question. Im trying to make a function that makes the thread wait without crashing the program which would result in something like the image above. [What Im trying to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ScnL.png)

I have tried using thread.sleep but it crashed the gui and also something like a Timeline or PauseTransition like this:

```
public static void wait(int milliseconds) {
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(milliseconds)));
        timeline.setOnFinished(event -> {

        });
        timeline.play();
    }
```

but it doesn't work since the javafx things work on a different thread.

edit: Something to keep in mind is that there isn't something specific to do after the pause so since the function doesn't know why I need the pause for it just needs to stop the main thread for x amount of time without crashing the gui.

Example of what I mean:

```
System.out.println("some information");
    pause(4000);
    System.out.println("idk");
    pause(1000);
    button.setVisible(true);
    pause(5000);
    MyImage.setImage(AImage);
```

Comment: *"it just needs to stop the main thread for x amount of time without crashing the gui"* -> by "stop" I guess you mean "block" (a stopped thread cannot be restarted) by "main thread" I guess you mean the JavaFX UI thread (the main thread is technically the thread that executes the `main` method, but the JavaFX UI thread is the thread that JavaFX executes on).  and by "crashing the gui" I guess you mean freezing the UI (if the application crashed it would exit).

Comment: Given those assumptions and definitions, if you block the JavaFX UI thread your application will freeze, so you basically never want to do that.

Comment: In that case what should I do?

Comment: [Background info on JavaFX concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60685975/1155209).

Comment: What do you mean by “make the thread wait”? The FX Application Thread isn’t actually going to do anything, unless you explicitly tell it to do something (eg in response to a user action or via as part of an animation). It’s not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, instead put the code in the question as text formatted as code.

Comment: Surely putting the button.setVisible and MyImage.setImage calls in the Timeline’s onFinished handler will do what you want?